# Table breaks in mobile breakpoint only, no solutions I have work. How to make this table responsive?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/vjakupi/pen/oNWpzwR

```
<div style="width: 100%;">

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%;">

                    <h3>Like you, we’ve made financial mistakes too.</h3>
                    <br>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%;">

                    <h3>Our goal is for you to need us less and less.</h3>
                    <br>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%;">

                    <h3>We strive to exceed your expectations every day.</h3>
                    <br>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%;">

                    <h3>We strive to exceed your expectations every day.</h3>

                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%;">

                    <p>No one is perfect, and we don’t expect you to be either. We strive to create an open, nonjudgmental space where you can share your concerns and worries without feeling embarrassed or less than you’re worth. Every one of us understands that managing your money is a huge responsibility, and we value having the opportunity to take some of the responsibility off your shoulders.</p>
                    <br>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%;">

                    <p>Through ongoing guidance and education, you’ll gain the confidence you need to make some of these decisions on your own. Of course, we’ll be here to guide you every step of the way, but throughout our partnership, we want to provide you with the knowledge and tools you need to manage your finances on your own as much as possible so you feel empowered to take control of your financial future.</p>
                    <br>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%;">

                    <p>While our efforts will be focused on helping you achieve your objectives, our ultimate goal is for you to surpass them. After all, you’re investing time, money and energy into working with us, and we want to make sure you’re getting maximum value out of our relationship. Throughout our time together, we’ll be constantly looking for new ways to get you closer to where you want to be.</p>
                    <br>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%;">

                    <p>While our efforts will be focused on helping you achieve your objectives, our ultimate goal is for you to surpass them. After all, you’re investing time, money and energy into working with us, and we want to make sure you’re getting maximum value out of our relationship. Throughout our time together, we’ll be constantly looking for new ways to get you closer to where you want to be.</p>
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my code. Currently, this table breaks when it goes to the mobile breakpoint and the table becomes cut off.

For the past two days, I have tried and failed to get this to work looking at CSS Trick guides and various videos. I can't figure out an effective way to make this table work in mobile with pure css.

I want it so when you go to mobile breakpoint around 360 px, all four columns collapse so each is on top of the other in the proper order. This makes the method of making them a block at breakpoint ineffective.

Anybody have any advice on how I can make this work? Is there something obvious with flex or grid I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `table` you may use grid or flexbox for responsiveness.

Here I had implemented the flexbox one

```css
.container
    {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

      @media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
        .container
        {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flexbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="first">
          <b>Like you, we’ve made financial mistakes too.</b>
          <p>No one is perfect, and we don’t expect you to be either. We strive to create an open, nonjudgmental space where you can share your concerns and worries without feeling embarrassed or less than you’re worth. Every one of us understands that managing your money is a huge responsibility, and we value having the opportunity to take some of the responsibility off your shoulders.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
          <b>Our goal is for you to need us less and less.</b>
          <p>Through ongoing guidance and education, you’ll gain the confidence you need to make some of these decisions on your own. Of course, we’ll be here to guide you every step of the way, but throughout our partnership, we want to provide you with the knowledge and tools you need to manage your finances on your own as much as possible so you feel empowered to take control of your financial future.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
          <b>We strive to exceed your expectations every day.</b>
          <p>While our efforts will be focused on helping you achieve your objectives, our ultimate goal is for you to surpass them. After all, you’re investing time, money and energy into working with us, and we want to make sure you’re getting maximum value out of our relationship. Throughout our time together, we’ll be constantly looking for new ways to get you closer to where you want to be.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fourth">
          <b>We strive to exceed your expectations every day.</b>
          <p>While our efforts will be focused on helping you achieve your objectives, our ultimate goal is for you to surpass them. After all, you’re investing time, money and energy into working with us, and we want to make sure you’re getting maximum value out of our relationship. Throughout our time together, we’ll be constantly looking for new ways to get you closer to where you want to be.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For responsiveness I had used **media query** when the width will go beyond 360px then the media-query block will get executed and it'll align all the `div` in column-wise manner. But on Big screen it will align the `div` in row-wise manner.